# Javascript Push array dosen't work

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hi i can't get my push function to work..

my code

```
   var result = {};


dpd.timesheetsdone.get(function (timesheets, err) {
  if(err) return console.log(err);

  timesheets.forEach(function(entry, index) {

   result[entry.timesheets[0].week] = [];
   result[entry.timesheets[0].week].push(entry);
     //heres my push
  }
   );
    setResult(result);

});
```

When runing it dosent push my entry, it just does like = and set result to 1 item, it dosen't push.

What could be the problem here ?

example of timesheets
http://pastebin.com/w2i7xYgm

Comment: What does the data you get back as `timesheets` look like? Because the way you're using it is ... very odd. Can you produce an [MCVE](/help/mcve)? There's clearly more to this...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder http://pastebin.com/w2i7xYgm

Comment: @Stweet: To improve your question, use the "edit" link rather than comments and external sites. (External links rot, and the question's purpose isn't just to help you, but to help others in the future.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
result[entry.timesheets[0].week] = [];
```

If you've ever put anything there before, that wipes it out; so you only ever see the *last* thing for that week.

You only want to do that assignment if you haven't already done it:

```
if (!result[entry.timesheets[0].week]) {
    result[entry.timesheets[0].week] = [];
}
```

E.g.:

```
var result = {};

dpd.timesheetsdone.get(function(timesheets, err) {
    if (err) return console.log(err);

    timesheets.forEach(function(entry, index) {

        if (!result[entry.timesheets[0].week]) {
            result[entry.timesheets[0].week] = [];
        }
        result[entry.timesheets[0].week].push(entry);
    });
    setResult(result);

});
```

Or to avoid repeated object lookups:

```
var result = {};

dpd.timesheetsdone.get(function(timesheets, err) {
    if (err) return console.log(err);

    timesheets.forEach(function(entry, index) {
        var week = entry.timesheets[0].week;
        var weekArray = result[week];
        if (!weekArray) {
            weekArray = result[week] = [];
        }
        weekArray.push(entry);
    });
    setResult(result);

});
```